# SQL NO CHECK FOREIGN KEY after data, re-enabling query optimizer

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

I have an SQL Server 2012 db with a foreign key constraint that references `Countries.CountryID = States.CountryID`

I needed to recreate `Countries` table so I DROP this FOREIGN KEY from the `States` table (otherwise it wouldn't allow me to DROP countries)

After I do that, I want to recreate the FK on `States` but it does not allow me to unless I specify `NO CHECK` as such:

```
ALTER TABLE States 
    WITH NOCHECK
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_StatesCountries FOREIGN KEY (CountryID) REFERENCES Countries(CountryID) 
GO
```

I didn't realize at first that some of the rows of States had `CountryID` that didnt have a matching `Countries.CountryID` record. Obviously `WITH NOCHECK` allowed me to proceed without error.

Now SQLServer with mark this FK as "not trusted", MSDN says to re-enable query optimizer by checking all constraints. So why is it that the following line does NOT give me an error even though some States have an invalid CountryID?

```
 ALTER TABLE States
      CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
 GO
```

I would think this should have raised an error.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To make the constraints trusted again, you'd need to use this syntax, which admittedly looks a bit strange. The `WITH CHECK` is what causes the validation of existing data.

```
 ALTER TABLE States
      WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
 GO
```

As before, this will throw an error until you resolve the States with bad CountryID values.